# How to get list of recipes by knife solo without cooking them

Tags: chef-infra, knife, knife-solo

I get a message like this after `knife solo cook nodename`.

```
Recipe: nginx::default
  * user[nginx] action create (up to date)
  * package[nginx] action install (up to date)
  * service[nginx] action enable (up to date)
  * service[nginx] action start (up to date)
```

How can I get the list of recipes without cooking them?